# Add double quotes to array elements

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using Datatables JQuery plugin and requires data elements to be wrapped in double quotes.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ticket #6,2015-05-20T19:36:02Z,open,normal,34
    [1] => testing org,2015-05-15T19:20:11Z,closed,,19
    [2] => testing ticket,2015-05-20T19:29:09Z,open,normal,29
    [3] => testing ticket #2 ,2015-05-20T19:30:55Z,open,normal,30
    [4] => ticket #3,2015-05-20T19:33:25Z,open,normal,31
    [5] => ticket #4,2015-05-20T19:34:32Z,open,normal,32
    [6] => ticket #5,2015-05-20T19:35:03Z,open,normal,33
)
```

I have tried using implode function, but haven't had success, I'm hoping if someone could help me achieving this task

Desired output:

```
"ticket #6","2015-05-20T19:36:02Z","open","normal","34"
```

so that when using json_encode it will be printed like this.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
       "ticket #6",
       "2015-05-20T19:36:02Z",
       "open",
       "normal",
       "34"

    ]

  ]
}
```

Comment: How exactly did you use `implode()`? Please code your code

Comment: What happens if one of the values contain a comma (`,`) character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just go through all of your array elements with `array_map()` and `explode()` them, e.g.

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
    return explode(",", $v));
}, $arr);
```

So with `json_encode()` you will end up with:

```
[
  ["ticket #6","2015-05-20T19:36:02Z","open","normal","34"],
  ["testing org","2015-05-15T19:20:11Z","closed","","19"],
  ["testing ticket","2015-05-20T19:29:09Z","open","normal","29"],
  ["testing ticket #2 ","2015-05-20T19:30:55Z","open","normal","30"],
  ["ticket #3","2015-05-20T19:33:25Z","open","normal","31"],
  ["ticket #4","2015-05-20T19:34:32Z","open","normal","32"],
  ["ticket #5","2015-05-20T19:35:03Z","open","normal","33"]
]
```

Comment: @Ghost yeah, thanks for the notice forgot about that.

Comment: sure man no prob, this should get the OP going